# Mongo DB find objects (arrays) from Object

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, nosql

I have object payResult: `[JAVA]`

```
   @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String branch;
    @Field
    private Map<String, ResultData<?>> successList;
    @Field
    private Map<String, ResultData<?>> failedList;
    private LocalDateTime createdTime = DateUtils.getDateTimeNow();
    @Indexed
    private String sessionId;
```

[image]

How to search object by name from failedList? I need get all '0108624656' objects from all failedList objects (arrays).

I need Query example, for using as native query in Spring Boot JPA

{failedList: {this : '0108624656'}} i tried this and  {failedList: {$exists: '0108624656'}} but its not result what i expected